# Python Flask: Send file and variable

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I have two servers where one is trying to get a file from the other.  I am using Flask get requests to send simple data back and forth (strings, lists, JSON objects, etc.).

I also know how to send just a file, but I need to send an error code with my data.

I'm using something along the following lines:

**Server 1:**

```
req = requests.post('https://www.otherserver.com/_download_file', data = {'filename':filename})
```

**Server 2:**

```
@app.route('/_download_file', methods = ['POST'])
def download_file():
    filename = requests.form.get('filename')

    file_data = codecs.open(filename, 'rb').read()
    return file_data
```

**Server 1:**

```
with codecs.open('new_file.xyz', 'w') as f:
    f.write(req.content)
```

...all of which works fine.  However, I want to send an error code variable along with `file_data` so that Server 1 knows the status (and not the HTTP status, but an internal status code).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there any special reason why HTTP error codes don't fill your need?

Comment: There are, but more importantly, I may also want to send information that is not an error code, but just additional data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One solution that comes to my mind is to use a custom HTTP header.

Here is an example server and client implementation.

Of course, you are free to change the name and the value of the custom header as you need.

**server**

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    response = send_from_directory(directory='your-directory', filename='your-file-name')
    response.headers['my-custom-header'] = 'my-custom-status-0'
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**client**

```
import requests

r = requests.post(url)

status = r.headers['my-custom-header']

# do what you want with status
```

**UPDATE**

Here is another version of the server based on your implementation

```
import codecs

from flask import Flask, request, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    filename = request.form.get('filename')

    file_data = codecs.open(filename, 'rb').read()
    response = make_response()
    response.headers['my-custom-header'] = 'my-custom-status-0'
    response.data = file_data
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this into my live code right now.  Either way, this is very helpful.  Thank you

Comment: good to see it helped you. I edited the answer to include another implementation based on yours.